# I'm getting a strange error when running here

Tags: c++, xcode, class, inheritance

Hi I'm getting an error that I've never seen before when running this code.  2 errors actually.

Here's the first   it says Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

```
"Address::setAddress(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced from:
```

Here's the second Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've got multiple classes in this program, so I've linked them to another site instead of bulking it up here.

Here's the link to my code
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/646f6e2166c56688f739

Thanks in advance guys.

```
void Address::setAddress(const string street, const string city, const string state, const string zipcode) {
setStreet(street);
setCity(city);
setState(state);
setZipcode(zipcode);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no realization of function `setAddress` in class `Address`, only declaration.

```
void setAddress(const string street, const string city, const string state, const string zipcode);
```

Comment: How would you set it? Considering all of the different variables.

Comment: @MatthewTingle it's your function. What do you want to ask? You call this function from `Employee::setAddress`, but you have no implementation of it.

Comment: I addded the setAddress into the post above. Now the build is succeeding, and opening the employeesOut.txt file but it isn't writing to it for some reason, no errors at all though.

Comment: I will open up another question, and accept your answer here, unless you want to continue this in chat.